# Can anyone help me with exact dep/landing times of specific historical flight?

Tags: delays

The flight is LHR to BKK with a stopover in Kuwait l. Flight with Kuwait Airways departing LHR on 29/12/16 at 15.35. Scheduled to arrive in BKK 21.15 30/12/16. The flight was delay d but I need to know exactly when it departed Kuwait and landed in Bangkok please?

KU0411 is flight number

Life saver if anyone could answer

Comment: I'm curious - whose life will that information save and HOW?